# Why AND logic function doesn't work in my case?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create shortcut when I press ctrl and space the inside function works, but it doesn't. I'm trying with `||` and it works.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode == 17) && (event.keyCode == 32)) {
        alert('Hello');
    }
});
```

Help please. Thank you.

Comment: Because `keyCode` cannot be both 17 AND 32...

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but like they said keycode cannot be both values at once, so I believe you will want to use the || operator

Comment: If you want to detect ctrl+space, then you want `event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 32`

Comment: You should rename this question to reflect what the code is trying to do. i.e "Creating keyboard shortcuts with multiple key press combinations"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [event.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) flag for the event.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 32) {
    alert('Hello');
  }
});
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; font-size: 2em; }
kbd { border: 3px #EEE outset; padding: 0.125em; }
```

```html
<p>Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.keyCode` cannot simultaneously have the values 17 and 32, so your condition does not make sense.